# How to handle cancelled/update VOIP push comes after the incoming call push has been handled

Tags: ios, swift, callkit, pushkit

We are trying to develop a VOIP app similar to WhatsApp that can receive incoming calls even when the app is killed or hasn't started. We are able to handle incoming calls however we have run into an issue where if we receive a VOIP push for an incoming call that is no longer active, or has already been handled we receive this error: "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Killing app because it never posted an incoming call to the system after receiving a PushKit VoIP push.'"

I have invoked the completion handler before it leaves the method. However I don't understand why it wants me to report an incoming call despite the push payload isn't for a incoming call but for updating one that is no longer available.

Is there a way to handle this scenario without running into this error? What is the way that iOS is expecting that for this to be handled?

I am fairly new to IOS development so I am still confused on the exact rules here, so any explation would be much appreciated.

Thank you very much,
Kwasi Asante

Comment: You must report an incoming call. It's as simple as that. If the incoming notification is for a call that is one for that is no longer available then report an incoming call and then immediately end the call.

Comment: @Paulw11 won't that still show the incoming call ui?

Comment: It may flash up for a split second, but probably not. It is what you need to do if you don't want your app to be terminated.

Comment: is there a reason why apple has it this way?

Comment: Maybe. You would have to ask them.  I suspect it is to ensure that apps do not abuse voip pushes (as some did in the past) to launch their app in the background when a call is not involved.